# Are VB.net References embedded in the compiled code?

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a commercial application in VB.Net using VS2010. My application needs to access a MySQL database. So I have a reference to MySQL.Data.dll in the "References" section of my Project. For licensing reasons, I want to make sure that this dll file is not embedded in my application. From what I read, if I set the "copy local" property to False, then the file is not copied and I need to specifically copy it to my bin directory. So I set it to False and built my project. When I run it, I can still connect to the MySQL database even though the dll is not in the bin directory. To me this indicates that it is being compiled with the build. However, the reference points to a location on my hard drive where the original MySQL.data.dll resides. Could it still find it there when the program is run?

How can I make sure it is not getting compiled? Thanks.

By the way, it is not in the GAC (I checked using gacutil.exe)

Comment: Did you try to run your application outside Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, and it still connects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to having the actual assembly embedded into yours, then no it does not. It can be done, but it does not happen out of the box.

The application looks at many places for your references when it needs to load it.

- GAC
- Next to the application (maybe also the consuming assembly)
- x64 and x86 folders next to the application (maybe also the consuming assembly)
- Any paths specified in the app.config/web.config for the referenced assembly.

Keep in mind that just because your application fired up, it doesn't mean it found all of the references. It more than likely hasn't loaded all of them yet as it will only do it once it is needed.

Comment: I brought the exe to another machine and ran it and I was not able to connect. So apparently it is not embedded. Thanks.